# How to pass files to WEB API from Android

Tags: android, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Web API service and Android Client to consume that service. Data parsing is working as expected. But now I have to transfer some documents/files to the web API. I have tried to pass in query parameter as string (after converting document to base64 string), which is working fine only for document having length of 2-3KB. But for large files (1-4MB) I get Socket timeout exception at android side I have tried with increasing the socket timeout for both android (okhttp client) and the web API from the C# code in controller.

please you can suggest me any other way that make it better. I know this is not the right way to pass files. I have max file size of 4-5 MB.

I am adding the code snippet of both Android and Web API. thanks in advance

C#:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResultModel SaveClaimDocument(string cd)
{ 
    HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
    .....
}
```

Android Code:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        OkHttpClient client = SingleConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnectionWithHighTimeOut();
        String url = "http://" + Constants.IP + "/api/ClaimDocuments/SaveClaimDocument?cd=" + file_base;

        try {
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                                        .addFormDataPart("test", cd)
                                        .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(url)
                                .post(requestBody)
                                .build();

            //Set Before New Connection Request
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
```

Edit: 
Android Exception
[image]

Comment: Can you post the output error string?

Comment: Sure for the Android?

Comment: @LeonardoG.Roese can you please Check that attached Screen shot for the android side exception.

Comment: Did you tried client.setConnectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);client.setReadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS); ?